# Can't run "gem list"!

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, zlib, rvm

I get an error when i run:

```
vagrant@vagrantup:~$ sudo gem list
ERROR:  Loading command: list (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::ListCommand
```

Even if I don't use sudo I get the same error message.

It's on Ubuntu 10.4 and I have installed zlib libraries:

```
vagrant@vagrantup:~$ sudo aptitude search zlib
p   gambas2-gb-compress-bzlib2                                                    - The Gambas bzlib2 component                                                             
p   gambas2-gb-compress-zlib                                                      - The Gambas zlib compression component                                                   
p   haskell-zlib-doc                                                              - Compression and decompression in the gzip and zlib formats; documentation               
p   libcompress-raw-zlib-perl                                                     - low-level interface to zlib compression library                                         
p   libcompress-zlib-perl                                                         - Transitional dummy package for Compress::Zlib                                           
i   libghc6-zlib-dev                                                              - Compression and decompression in the gzip and zlib formats                              
v   libghc6-zlib-dev-0.5.2.0-d3bd7                                                -                                                                                         
v   libghc6-zlib-doc                                                              -                                                                                         
p   libghc6-zlib-prof                                                             - Compression and decompression in the gzip and zlib formats; profiling libraries         
v   libghc6-zlib-prof-0.5.2.0-d3bd7                                               -                                                                                         
p   libio-compress-zlib-perl                                                      - Transitional dummy package for IO::Compress::Zlib                                       
p   libio-zlib-perl                                                               - IO:: style interface to gzip/zlib compressed files/handles                              
p   libjzlib-java                                                                 - reimplementation of zlib in pure Java                                                   
i   libzlib-ruby                                                                  - transitional dummy package                                                              
v   libzlib-ruby1.8                                                               -                                                                                         
p   zlib-bin                                                                      - compression library - sample programs                                                   
i   zlib1g                                                                        - compression library - runtime                                                           
p   zlib1g-dbg                                                                    - compression library - development                                                       
i   zlib1g-dev                                                                    - compression library - development                                                       
i   zlibc                                                                         - An on-fly auto-uncompressing C library
```

Im using http://www.vagrantup.com and the error comes after i have installed rvm.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Having the same problem in Ubuntu 10.10, and the accepted answer doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How was Ruby installed?  If Ruby was installed without zlib support, that would be the problem.

You can read my article [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux.htm) on installing RVM on Ubuntu.  You must have both zlib and the zlib-dev packages installed before compiling Ruby (along with some other packages from Ubuntu).  You'll probably just need to install these and re-compile Ruby.